# Propose New Meeting Time not supported by Office 365 Graph API

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, office365api

When you arrange a meeting and one of the attendees responds by proposing a new time, it is not possible to see the newly proposed time on the message object returned by the Office 365 Graph API.

Here is an example of the message object for such a response from the /messages endpoint:

```
{
        "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.eventMessage",
        "@odata.etag": "W/\"DAAAABYAAABScDrPb+rMTZOocc5vRCTLAAG358aD\"",
        "id": "AAMkADQ3MDg1NWRmLTUxMGQtNDRiMi1iMGE4LTAzMzdjNGRiYTIxNQBGAAAAAADEPuholyn_QpUTcq2qMEH4BwBScDrPb_rMTZOocc5vRCTLAAAAAAEMAABScDrPb_rMTZOocc5vRCTLAAG3qsuFAAA=",
        "createdDateTime": "2017-05-10T09:51:28Z",
        "lastModifiedDateTime": "2017-05-10T09:51:28Z",
        "changeKey": "DAAAABYAAABScDrPb+rMTZOocc5vRCTLAAG358aD",
        "categories": [],
        "receivedDateTime": "2017-05-10T09:51:28Z",
        "sentDateTime": "2017-05-10T09:51:26Z",
        "hasAttachments": false,
        "internetMessageId": "<HE1PR03MB3099233327E51F1BB6B2D56BABEC0@HE1PR03MB3099.eurprd03.prod.outlook.com>",
        "subject": "New Time Proposed: Test event",
        "bodyPreview": "",
        "importance": "normal",
        "parentFolderId": "AAMkADQ3MDg1NWRmLTUxMGQtNDRiMi1iMGE4LTAzMzdjNGRiYTIxNQAuAAAAAADEPuholyn_QpUTcq2qMEH4AQBScDrPb_rMTZOocc5vRCTLAAAAAAEMAAA=",
        "conversationId": "AAQkADQ3MDg1NWRmLTUxMGQtNDRiMi1iMGE4LTAzMzdjNGRiYTIxNQAQAOSfIUrJuYZEhvDlXsNH9lc=",
        "isDeliveryReceiptRequested": null,
        "isReadReceiptRequested": false,
        "isRead": false,
        "isDraft": false,
        "webLink": "https://outlook.office365.com/owa/?ItemID=AAMkADQ3MDg1NWRmLTUxMGQtNDRiMi1iMGE4LTAzMzdjNGRiYTIxNQBGAAAAAADEPuholyn%2BQpUTcq2qMEH4BwBScDrPb%2BrMTZOocc5vRCTLAAAAAAEMAABScDrPb%2BrMTZOocc5vRCTLAAG3qsuFAAA%3D&exvsurl=1&viewmodel=ReadMessageItem",
        "inferenceClassification": "focused",
        "meetingMessageType": "meetingTenativelyAccepted",
        "body": {
            "contentType": "html",
            "content": "<html>\r\n<head>\r\n<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\">\r\n<meta content=\"text/html; charset=us-ascii\">\r\n<style type=\"text/css\" style=\"display:none\">\r\n<!--\r\np\r\n\t{margin-top:0;\r\n\tmargin-bottom:0}\r\n-->\r\n</style>\r\n</head>\r\n<body dir=\"ltr\">\r\n<div id=\"divtagdefaultwrapper\" dir=\"ltr\" style=\"font-size:12pt; color:#000000; font-family:Calibri,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif\">\r\n<p><br>\r\n</p>\r\n</div>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n"
        },
        "sender": {
            "emailAddress": {
                "name": "Sebastian Leonaris",
                "address": "sebastian@company.com"
            }
        },
        "from": {
            "emailAddress": {
                "name": "Sebastian Leonaris",
                "address": "sebastian@company.com"
            }
        },
        "toRecipients": [
            {
                "emailAddress": {
                    "name": "Laura Sinestra",
                    "address": "laura@company.com"
                }
            }
        ],
        "ccRecipients": [],
        "bccRecipients": [],
        "replyTo": []
    }
```

Is this a bug in the Office 365 Graph API, or is there some other way of achieving this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

six years later, new time proposed is available.

Partial results from https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/*MessageId*:

```
   ],
"ccRecipients": [],
"bccRecipients": [],
"replyTo": [],
"flag": {
    "flagStatus": "notFlagged"
},
"startDateTime": {
    "dateTime": "2023-03-14T13:00:00.0000000",
    "timeZone": "UTC"
},
"endDateTime": {
    "dateTime": "2023-03-14T13:30:00.0000000",
    "timeZone": "UTC"
},
"recurrence": null,
"proposedNewTime": {
    "start": {
        "dateTime": "2023-03-14T14:30:00.0000000",
        "timeZone": "UTC"
    },
    "end": {
        "dateTime": "2023-03-14T15:00:00.0000000",
        "timeZone": "UTC"
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This is not yet supported.  We have it on our roadmap, and but don't have a timeframe yet to release this support in the API.